# serialize a XML, remove try-catch insert instead a if

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

Is there any way to remove the try-catch and to the same work with an if???

```
    try
    {
        StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(GUID, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        if (sessionFile == null)
            return Guid.Empty;

        using (IInputStream sessionInputStream = await sessionFile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            var sessionSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Guid));
            return (Guid)sessionSerializer.ReadObject(sessionInputStream.AsStreamForRead());
        }
    }
    catch (System.Xml.XmlException e)
    {
        return Guid.Empty;
    }
```

I think I get the Exception if the file is no in a XML format, or??

Comment: What exception do you get, can you post your exception?

Comment: As long as any of the statements can throw the XMLException then I wouldn't want to loose the try/catch.

Comment: Unexpected end of file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, basically. There is no `TryReadObject` method, and it would not be a normal feature of most serializers to have such. You could of course *add* a `TryReadObject` *extension* method, i.e.

```
public static T TryReadObject<T>(this IInputStream sessionInputStream, out T value)
{
    try
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T));
        using(var stream = sessionInputStream.AsStreamForRead())
        {
            value = (T)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        value = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

but that just moves the exception handling. But then you could use:

```
StorageFile sessionFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(GUID, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
if (sessionFile == null)
    return Guid.Empty;

using (IInputStream sessionInputStream = await sessionFile.OpenReadAsync())
{
    Guid val;
    return sessionInputStream.TryReadObject<Guid>(out val) ? val : Guid.Empty;
}
```

Comment: @MichaelEckhart-Wöllkart note that I edited to tidy it up a bit